# library problems in R

Tags: r, package

I installed the package required and set my library using `install.packages("bipartite",lib="C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")`

When i finish installing package, it says the downloaded binary packages are in `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuGqI8Q\downloaded_packages`

I checked my directory using `dir()`, all the things in package bipartite are in `C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork`

When i try to load the package using this command, `library("bipartite", lib.loc="C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")` the error appear

Error: package ‘vegan’ required by ‘bipartite’ could not be found
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘bipartite’ was built under R version 3.3.3

Checked my `dir()` again and it stated that there is a "vegan' in my working directory

Tried to look at `.libPaths()` it show this

```
[1] "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"

[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library"
```

How do i solve this? Do i need to change the library path?

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your error. It looks like R does not install the dependencies. This works however:

```
library(permute, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(vegan, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(statnet.common, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(network, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(sna, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(bipartite, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
```

It's just a workaround. Maybe this can also help:

```
library(devtools)
load_all("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
```

Comment: Tried to use "library(devtools)" and
"load_all("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")" error happens. I also tried these command, "library(permute, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(vegan, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(statnet.common, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(network, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(sna, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")
library(bipartite, lib.loc = "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork")" the same error occurs. saying there is no certain package in the installed package

Comment: Strange, using the library function in the right order should solve the issue. Anyways, try just to append library paths by your local path by using `.libPaths(c(.libPaths(), "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Rwork"))`; now using `library(bipartite)` should install `bipartite` and it's dependencies.

Comment: I think there's no need to change the library path. Knowing where the library is should be okay. Btw, i already solved this issue using "library(package)". Perhaps ".libPaths()" or "lib.loc" function only to know where our library is? Thank you by the way for your help